# Тормозит DataGrid при больших объёмах данных

Tags: c#, wpf

Вывожу массив `byte[,]` размером 200x200 в DataGrid таким образом:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = FillDataGrig(<массив>);
...
public DataView FillDataGrig(byte[,] array)
{
    int rows = array.GetLength(0);
    int columns = array.GetLength(1);
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn((i + 1).ToString()));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        DataRow newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            newRow[j] = array[i, j];
        }
        dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }

    return dataTable.DefaultView;
}
```

Скроллинг такого DataGrid тормозит, как и сам рендер. Можно это как-то исправить?

---

**UPDATE:** Окей, раз DataGrid так плох, то сделал через `ItemsControl`, но всё равно большие массивы (300х300) выводит по несколько минут.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" BorderBrush="#E6E6E6">
            <Label Content="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="1">
                <Label.Style>                        
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#D7D7D7"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Label.Style>
            </Label>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level1">            
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level2}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>            
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

...

<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="grid1" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level1}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Вывожу так:

```
grid1.ItemsSource = список списков (List<List<byte>>) ;
```

Comment: Непонятно зачем вы все это пишете в DataTable? И непонятно какой функционал DataGrid вам нужен, может вам подойдёт обычный ItemsControl?

Comment: DataGrid не нужен практически никогда. Ну разве что вы не хотите абстрагировать таблицы для юзера.

Comment: @VladD Тогда через что я должен выводить двумерные массивы для просмотра пользователю (без редактирования, сортировок и тд, только просмотр) с возможностью "подсветки" определённых ячеек?

Comment: @Jagailo: Выводить двумерные массивы пользователю? Странный интерфейс для программы. А для чего они пользователю? Какой у них смысл?

Comment: @VladD Требование такое. Вот пример: [пример 1](https://i.imgur.com/5z0CNIt.png), [пример 2](https://i.imgur.com/MjNUmQh.png)

Comment: @Jagailo: Ну, требование как требование. А почему `DataGrid`? Чем вам обыкновенный `ItemsControl` не угодил?

Comment: @VladD Я в WPF новичок и долго не догонял что такое `ItemsControl`. В итоге сделал по примеру из [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276808/how-to-populate-a-wpf-grid-based-on-a-2-dimensional-array). Спасибо.

Comment: @VladD Сделал через ItemsControl и каждая ячейка - это Label. Вывод массива 300х300 занимает минуты 2-3, это нормально?

Comment: @Jagailo: Нет, не нормально, что-то вы делаете не так. Должно быть мгновенно.

Comment: @VladD Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я немного ускорил ваш код за счёт виртуализации. Вертикальный скроллинг всё ещё медленный.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="InnerBorderStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#D7D7D7"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" BorderBrush="#E6E6E6"
                Height="30" Width="30" Style="{StaticResource InnerBorderStyle}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Padding="1"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate_Level2}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

```
<ListView VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate_Level1}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          MouseLeftButtonUp="Window_MouseLeftButtonUp">
    <!-- отключаем подсветку строки под курсором мыши -->
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Данные задаются через `DataContext` (это важно для виртуализации). И отсутствие «явного» `ScrollViewer`'а тоже важно.