# Изменить шаблон ячейки DataGrid в зависимости от значения данной ячейки

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-шаблоны

У меня есть DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="messageGrid" BorderBrush="#FFF0F0F0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Date}" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" Header="Дата" IsReadOnly="True" Width="200"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn  CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" Header="Квитирование" Width="200">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
                <local:EditorTemplateSelector/>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Text}" CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" Header="Сообщение" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Шаблон столбца с заголовком "Квитирование" необходимо менять в зависимости от значения, записанного в этой ячейке. Условно говоря, если значение равно "Text1" - то ячейка содержит в себе кнопку,  если "Text2" - текстовое поле с текстом "Text2". Для этого завел класс EditorTEmplateSelector

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
{
    string editorType = "";
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(editorType))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        if (editorType.Contains("Не квитировано"))
        {
            return (DataTemplate)((FrameworkElement)container).FindResource("nonKvited");
        }
        else
        {
            return (DataTemplate)((FrameworkElement)container).FindResource("Kvited");
        }
    }
}
```

И 2 шаблона в ресурсах:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="nonKvited">
        <Button Name="PART_Editor" Content="Квитировать" Margin="1,1,1,1" Click="KvitInGridClick" CommandParameter="{Binding RowData.Row}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Kvited">
        <TextBlock Name="PART_Editor" Text="{Binding Kvited}" Margin="1,1,1,1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Но я никак не могу получить информацию о том, что записано в ячейку и поэтому переключатель шаблонов не работает.
Как вообще можно реализовать подобное изменение шаблона ячейки грида?

Comment: `<Style.Triggers>` пробовали?

Comment: а в качестве `Property` при этом использовать что? `DataTemplate`?

Comment: @Jagailo, для какого элемента выставлять триггеры?

Comment: [Вот пример](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/10.2.php) использования. Проверить сам не могу, так как WPF в вижле и не установлен.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/728074/180980 
Посмотрите тут вариант с изменение `background` в ячейке из-за значения в ней

Comment: Изменение фона ячейки не совсем схоже с изменением ее шаблона, но спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Так это же как пример, думаю там можно разного прикрутить.

Comment: В общем я решил свою проблему, решение подсказал https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340606/wpf-datagrid-celltemplateselector-item

Comment: Можете опубликовать своё решение как ответ, чтобы помось другим участникам в будущем.

Answer (score 0):

Из за того, что делаю UserControl пришлось немного извернуться и накинуть пару статических свойств:

```
public static DataTemplate NonKvitedTemplate;
public static DataTemplate KvitedTemplate;
public Messages()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NonKvitedTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("nonKvited");
    KvitedTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("Kvited");
}
```

Далее непосредственно классы для работы с шаблонами

```
public abstract class PropertyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    private Delegate getPropertyValue;
    private string propertyName;
    private Type itemType;

    public string PropertyName
    {
        get
        {
            return propertyName;
        }
        set
        {
            propertyName = value;
        }
    }

    public Type ItemType
    {
        get
        {
            return itemType;
        }
        set
        {
            itemType = value;
        }
    }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (ItemType.IsInstanceOfType(item))
        {
            if (getPropertyValue == null)
            {
                System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression instanceParameter =
                    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(item.GetType(), "p");

                System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression currentExpression =
                    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.PropertyOrField(instanceParameter, PropertyName);

                System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression lambdaExpression =
                    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(currentExpression, instanceParameter);

                getPropertyValue = lambdaExpression.Compile();
            }

            return SelectTemplateImpl(getPropertyValue.DynamicInvoke(item), container);
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }

    protected abstract DataTemplate SelectTemplateImpl(object propertyValue, DependencyObject container);
}

public class NameTemplateSelector : PropertyTemplateSelector
{
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateImpl(object propertyValue, DependencyObject container)
    {
        string name = (string)propertyValue;

        if (name != null && name.Contains("Не квитировано"))
        {
            return Messages.NonKvitedTemplate;
        }

        return Messages.KvitedTemplate;
    }
}
```

Далее ресурсы окна:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="nonKvited">
        <Button Name="PART_Editor" Content="Квитировать" Margin="1,1,1,1" Click="KvitInGridClick" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Row}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Kvited">
        <TextBlock Name="PART_Editor" Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=Kvited}" Margin="1,1,1,1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:NameTemplateSelector x:Key="NameTemplateSelector" PropertyName="Kvited" ItemType="{x:Type local:Message}" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

И сама колонка грида

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn  CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="False" Header="Квитирование" Width="200" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource NameTemplateSelector}" />
```