# В DataGrid добавить кнопки

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю проект в котором отображается таблица и в последней колонке в зависимости от данных в таблице sql планировал или текст или кнопка, если в базе значение null то отображается кнопка если есть какойто текст то вывести этот текст. 
  Использую автогенерацию колонок AutoGenerateColumns=true.
все что находил в интернете не работает, возможно ли такое сделать? Если да подскажите метод

Comment: выключить автогенерацию и рисовать в ячейках строки то, что вам нужно

Comment: а через  DataGridTemplateColumn dataGridTextColumn = e.Column as DataGridTemplateColumn; не получится?

Comment: а откуда `DataGridTemplateColumn` возьмется в гриде, если вы его туда не засунете?

Comment: Проблема еще в том что в колонке может быть или кнопка или текст

Comment: пишете свой контрол, который будет при одном условии показываться как кнопка, при другом - как текст. Вставляете этот контрол в таблицу. Профит

Comment: А есть какой нибудь пример? чтото я ни как не могу сделать. Нашел вот такой пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/873981/326664 то что мне надо, но у меня чтото не работает он

Comment: уж не знаю как вы ищете, [четвертая ссылка в гугле](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/ru/89/%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-datagrid/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D1%8B-datagrid/)

Comment: не нашел того что мне поможет создать в отдом столбце разные шаблоны

Comment: зачем вам разные шаблоны? Вам нужен конкретный шаблон из текстблока и кнопки, и при одном условии вы скрываете текстблок, при другом - кнопку

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [TemplateSelector](https://www.wpftutorial.net/datatemplates.html) - позволяет выбирать темплейты в зависемости от данных, которые находятся в моделе.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал следующим образом

```
 <Window.Resources>
            <local:StatusConverter x:Key="StatusConverter"></local:StatusConverter>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Button Name="btn1" Content="Отметить" Width="145" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="containerEntry" Background="LightGreen"
                                    Visibility="{Binding Status,Converter={StaticResource StatusConverter},ConverterParameter=a}"></Button>
                                <TextBlock Name="btn2"  Text="{Binding DateIn, StringFormat={}{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}}" Width="150"
                                    Visibility="{Binding Status,Converter={StaticResource StatusConverter},ConverterParameter=b}"></TextBlock>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

конвертер

```
class StatusConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            GridContainer result = new GridContainer();
            StatusEnum status = (StatusEnum)value;
            string param = parameter as string;
            if ((status == StatusEnum.Success && param == "a") || (status == StatusEnum.Failed && param == "b"))
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }


    enum StatusEnum
    {
        Success,
        Failed            
    }
}
```